# How do I retrieve images from our AWS to put dynamically onto BIRT report (eclipse)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, birt

I am trying to retrieve an image for my birt report from AWS but everytime I put in the URI and click Insert I get this error:

[image]

Then when I click Ok, I get this:

[[image]

I also get this when i try and run the report

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this ? Any ideas on what I have to do to make it work please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I was out of memory.
Added this ling to my eclipse.ini and worked like a charm!:

-Xmx4g